# Пополение коллекции моделями из сервера. Backbone: Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Мне нужно пополнить модель данными, полученными из сервера. На этапе запроса к серверу я получаю ошибку:

> Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

`urlRoot` задал, не работает.

Что я упустил?

```
var Fruit = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var apple = new Fruit({urlRoot: '/path/to/api'});
apple.has('urlRoot'); // true
apple.fetch() // Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

Comment: Как бы 'url' не равно 'urlRoot'.

Comment: @edem сначала пробовал `url` использовать. ошибку выдает ту же

Comment: А еще в последней строчке в слове `appple` лишнее `p`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev опечатку поправил, но картина осталась той же

Comment: @nuda.works, читайте мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 1):

Параметр `urlRoot`, как впрочем и `url`, должен задаваться при создании *типа* моделей. Вы же передаете поле `urlRoot`, как один из *атрибутов* модели. Это не правильно. Рабочий код может иметь вид:

```
var Fruit = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/path/to/api'
});

// Для получения реального URL модели, параметр urlRoot будет объединен с ID.
// Backbone будет пытаться загрузить модель из "/path/to/api/foo".
var apple = new Fruit({id: 'foo'});
apple.fetch();
```

Comment: @DmitrySimushev разобрался. спасибо за помощь!